# DOMPDF table header

Tags: html, codeigniter

How to make

```
<tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
            <th>e</th>
        </tr>
```

always printable on every page.

My View

```
<style>
             @page { margin: 150px 50px; }
             #header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -100px; right: 0px; height: 50px; text-align: center; }
             #footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: -180px; right: 0px; height: 150px; text-align: center; }
             #footer .page:after { content: counter(page, upper-roman); }
           </style>

        <div id="header">
             <h1>Tittle</h1>
           </div>

        <div id="content">
        <?php
        echo"<table class='gridtable'>";
        ?>
    <table width="100%" page-break-inside: auto;>

            <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
            <th>e</th>
        </tr>


        <?php
        $num = 0;
        foreach($result as $key=>$val){
            $num++;
                echo"<tr>
                            <td>".$a."</td>".
                            "<td>".$val['b']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$val['c']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$val['d']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$val['e']."</td>".
                            "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
        </table>
        <?php
        echo"</table>";
        ?>
        </div>
        <script type="text/php">

            if ( isset($pdf) ) {

              $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");
              $pdf->page_text(280, 780, "Page {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));

            }
            </script>
```

For Example, Here is my PDF after i downloaded

1st page :

```
| Title 1 | Tittle 2 | Tittle 3 |
| row 1   | row 1    | row 1    |
```

2nd page :

```
| row 2   | row 2    | row 2    |
```

How to make 2nd page like this :

```
| Title 1 | Tittle 2 | Tittle 3 |
| row 2   | row 2    | row 2    |
```

I want the Tittle always printed on top every page. Thank You

Comment: Please expand upon your problem

Answer (score 13):

In recent versions of DOMPDF (e.g., version 0.5.2 or later, I believe), you can wrap your rows containing your table headers in a THEAD.

Change your view to:

```
<table width="100%" page-break-inside: auto;>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
            <th>e</th>
       </tr>
   <thead>
```

This should do the trick. There is one case where it fails: if your table is rendered so that it breaks after your `thead` but before any data rows are rendered, the `thead` will not show up on the next page. If the table breaks across yet another page, the `thead` will show up on the subsequent pages.

Comment: Incidentally, if you want to fix that "one case" mentioned above, edit table_row_group_frame_decorator.cls.php and change the code starting at line 55:

        if ( $child === $this->get_first_child() ) {
      $cellmap->remove_row_group($this);
      parent::split();
      return;
    }

to 

    if ( $child === $this->get_first_child() ) {
      $cellmap->remove_row_group($this);
      parent::split($child);
      return;
    }

I don't know if there are other side effects, but it worked for me.

Comment: As of version what? also is it DMPDF or DOMPDF?

Comment: Sorry, typo. It should be DOMPDF. And when I state "recent," I believe it should be version 0.5.2 or later. I've been working with the version 0.6.0 beta. Updated the answer to refelect that.

Comment: Nowadays 2023, that one case still persists in last version, the way I've found to avoid it is to apply page-break-after:avoid <thead> <tr style="page-break-after:avoid;"> your row </tr></thead>

Comment: If you're still running into issues, make sure that no table cell spans more than a single page.